# How to use post manner to transmit username and password in order to log in a website on iphone or ipad platform?

Tags: iphone, ipad, post, asihttprequest

How to use post manner to transmit username and password in order to log in a website  on iphone or ipad platform?

Some one has suggest me that use ASIHTTPRequest,but I don't know how to use it．
Can somebody help me ?Thank you ........

Answer (score 2):

ASIHTTPRequest has one of the best how to use pages of any library I have ever encountered.  It is located here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

If you need to post to a web form you could do something like this:

```
#define kURLString @"https://yourwebsite.com"
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:kURLString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"myname" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"l33td00d" forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Although in real life you may wish to run the request asynchronous.  The details on how to do that are on the page I linked.  It is defiantly worth reading.

Comment: Can more detail?I try your code in my project but I don't know how it work ,it the effect ??